# Multiple checkboxes to trigger a js script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple lists generated inside a while loop. Each list has a group id assigned to it, and stored in a variable. Each list item has a checkbox. I want to be able to have a "Select All" option below each list.

Whilst the code I have works fine for a single list, with multiple lists it only ever works on one of them.
I believe this is due to each list having the same class name on the checkbox. I could append  the group id to each class, but that would mean having the script inside the while loop, which I was told in the past is not correct.

An example of my current checkbox code for each list item is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1881:b4568df26077653eeadf29596708c94b]" id="cl-checkbox1881:b4568df26077653eeadf29596708c94b" class="cl-checkbox" onclick="clRowSelection(this);" />
```

There could be multiples of this per group.

My "Select All" checkbox code is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cl_select_all_1" id="cl-checkall" />
```

and there will be one of these for each group.

And my script is

```
jQuery("#cl-checkall").change(function() {
    jQuery(".cl-checkbox").prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked"));
});

jQuery('.cl-checkbox').change(function() { 
    if(false == jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
        jQuery("#cl-checkall").prop('checked', false);
    }
    if (jQuery('.cl-checkbox:checked').length == jQuery('.cl-checkbox').length ){
        jQuery("#cl-checkall").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

I read that I can use something like data-groupID="mygroupID", and then pass that into the script using $(this) so it knows which checkbox was selected.

I believe I need to do this for the list:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[1881:b4568df26077653eeadf29596708c94b]" id="cl-checkbox1881:b4568df26077653eeadf29596708c94b" class="cl-checkbox" data-groupID="mygroupID" onclick="clRowSelection(this);" />
```

and this for the select all:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cl_select_all_1" id="cl-checkall" data-groupID="mygroupID"/>
```

but I'm stuck on how to add

```
$(this).data('groupID')
```

to the script to get it working.

I may be completely wrong in my understanding of the use of $(this) as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your select all change handler, you can select just the inputs that match your current `groupID`

```
jQuery(".cl-checkall").change(function() {
    jQuery('.cl-checkbox[data-groupID="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]')
        .prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

This is effectively what you have already, but we're adding the data selector to the jQuery search to exclude the other checkboxes on the page.

The `jQuery(this).data("groupid")` (jQuery requires data attribute names to be lower case) will return the data attribute for the changed element, and the `[data-groupID="x"]` will only match elements with the groupID `x`

(As you now have multiple of them, you will probably also want to start using a class on the select-all checkbox instead of an ID, I've changed it to using `.cl-checkall`)

The same changes can be applied to the individual checkbox listener, only selecting the select-all with the matching data attribute.

```
jQuery('.cl-checkbox').change(function() { 
    if(false == jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {
        jQuery('.cl-checkall[data-groupID="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
    if (jQuery('.cl-checkbox[data-groupID="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]:checked').length == jQuery('.cl-checkbox[data-groupID="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]').length ){
        jQuery('.cl-checkall[data-groupID="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't seem to be able to get this working. I set up a quick fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zfk847Lh/

Comment: Sorry, missed a section of the jquery out. https://jsfiddle.net/zfk847Lh/1/

Comment: @Steph3071 Oh, I forgot that jQuery needs data attribute names in lower case, you need to look for `groupid`, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Changed all instances of groupID to groupid and it works now. Thanks for the help, and a really good explanation.