# Identifying which class made the request with jquery data selector in AJAX form submission

Tags: jquery

I have a series of groups, each of which contains lists of items. I have added decrement/increment buttons to the quantity field, and want this to work via AJAX.

Sample html for one of the input fields is

```
<div class="ContentCell list_product_qty_wrapper nbr nbt">
  <input type="text" name="cartlist_quantity" value="1" size="4" class="cart_input_1881" />
  <input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="1881" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cartlist_group_id" value="1" />
</div>
```

The full script where the increment/decrement buttons are added to the input field, and AJAX call is initiated is

```
// Add Increment/Decrement buttons
function add_quantity_buttons(element, vertical) {
  quantity_input = jQuery(element);
  quantity_input.attr('min', '0').attr('inputmode', 'numeric').attr('pattern', '[0-9]*').addClass('inc_dec_quantity_field').wrap('<div class="quantity_field_wrapper clearfix"></div>');

  if (jQuery('.device-xs').is(':visible')) {
    quantity_input.attr('type', 'number');
  } else {
    quantity_input.attr('type', 'text');
  }

  quantity_input.before('<a href="#decrease_quantity" class="quantity_dec_button">-</a>').after('<a href = "#increase_quantity" class = "quantity_inc_button" > + </a>');
}

// Handle quantity buttons
// Increment/Decrement button functionality
function increment_decrement_quantity(element, value) {
  $(document.body).on('click', element, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    quantity = $(this).parent().find(('input'));
    quantity_value = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);
    quantity_multiple = undefined;

    if (quantity.data('multiple') !== undefined && (quantity.data('multiple') > 0 || quantity.data('multiple') < 0)) {
      quantity_multiple = parseInt(quantity.data('multiple'), 10);
      if (value < 0) {
        quantity_multiple = quantity_multiple * -1;
      }
    }

    if (quantity_multiple !== undefined && (quantity_multiple > 0 || quantity_multiple < 0)) {
      quantity_value = Math.floor(quantity_value / quantity_multiple) * quantity_multiple;
      value = quantity_multiple;
    } else {
      value = parseInt(value, 10);
    }

    // Validate quantity and increment/decrement value
    if (value > 0 || value < 0 && quantity_value > 0) {
      quantity.val(quantity_value + value).trigger('change');
    }
  });
}

// Remove number type and add quantity change buttons
add_quantity_buttons('#listContentsDisplay input[name^="cartlist_quantity"]', true);

// Decrement button
increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_dec_button', -1);

// Increment button
increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_inc_button', +1);

// Quantity input validation
var ajax_called = false;
$(document.body).on('propertychange change click keyup input paste blur', '.inc_dec_quantity_field', function(e) {
  character_code = !e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode;
  quantity_value = $(this).val();
  leading_zero_plus_regexp = /^(0[0-9]|\+[\+,0-9]).*$/;

  // When input goes out of focus validate quantity value
  if (e.type == 'blur' && (quantity_value == '' || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == true || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value <= 0)) {
    $(this).val('0');
  } else {
    // Check for numeric value and allow backspace, delete, left and right arrows
    if ((isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value > 0) || (character_code != undefined && (character_code == 39 || character_code == 37 || character_code == 8 || character_code == 46))) {
      // Correct value
      // Make sure the quantity is integer
      if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
        $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
      }
    } else if (character_code != undefined) {
      // Incorrect value
      $(this).val('0');
    } else if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
      // Make sure the quantity is integer
      $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
    }
  }

  // AJAX update quantity
  //if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper') && !ajax_called) {
  //if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper[data-groupid="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]') && !ajax_called) {
 // if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().data('groupid') == jQuery(this).data("groupid") && !ajax_called) { changed to this after suggestion from Ivan (SO)
  if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).data('groupid') == jQuery(this).data("groupid") && !ajax_called) { // Ivan (SO) suggestion didn't give an 'OK' in console log. Removing .parent().parent(), it does give an ok, but still only submits the last group to AJAX update 
    console.log('OK');
    call_delay(function() {
      var form = $('form[name="cartlist"]');
      ajax_called = true;
      $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize()
      }).success(function(data) {

      if ($('#cartlistDefault').length && $(data).find('#cartlistDefault').length) {
        $('#cartlistDefault').replaceWith($(data).find('#cartlistDefault'));

          // Remove number type and add quantity change buttons
          add_quantity_buttons('#listContentsDisplay input[name^="cartlist_quantity"]', true);
          // Replace classes missing after AJAX callback
          $('select').addClass('select_caret_icon form-control');
          if ($('input[type="submit"].cssButton').length > 0) {
            $('input[type="submit"].cssButton').attr("data-btn", "btn btn-md");
          }
        }

        ajax_called = false;
      }).fail(function(data) {
        ajax_called = false;
      });
    }, 300);
  }
});
```

My issue is that the increment only works for the last group generated in the `while` loop.

Based on a question I asked yesterday ([Multiple checkboxes to trigger a js script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155728/multiple-checkboxes-to-trigger-a-js-script)) where I had similar issues with identifying which group a request had come from, I tried the same approach here,

replacing

```
<div class="ContentCell list_product_qty_wrapper nbr nbt">
```

with

```
<div class="ContentCell list_product_qty_wrapper nbr nbt" data-groupid="1">
```

and in the script, replacing

```
if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper') && !ajax_called) {
```

with

```
if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper[data-groupid="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]') && !ajax_called) {
```

After doing this though, none of the increment buttons trigger the AJAX process.

This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8h4gzmu3/ shows what the input field and increment/decrement looks like, and whist the buttons do actually update the quantities when clicked, once the AJAX call has finished, the first and second inputs are not updated. ONLY the last one is.

Clearly I've not quite grasped the concept of using the data selector.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using hasClass that looking at class not at attributes and in html you are adding data-groupid as attribute

you can try this one should work if parent data-groupid is same at this

```
if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().data('groupid') == jQuery(this).data("groupid") && !ajax_called) {
```

**UPDATE**

you can follow this logic to do it , add same groupid for buttons and current input then in if statment match them to each other .

here is the example that match current input , if you change the input groupid different from button groupid if statment will be FALSE and you wont get console log

```js
// Add Increment/Decrement buttons
function add_quantity_buttons(element, vertical) {
  quantity_input = jQuery(element);
  quantity_input.attr('min', '0').attr('inputmode', 'numeric').attr('pattern', '[0-9]*').addClass('inc_dec_quantity_field').wrap('<div class="quantity_field_wrapper clearfix"></div>');

  if (jQuery('.device-xs').is(':visible')) {
    quantity_input.attr('type', 'number');
  } else {
    quantity_input.attr('type', 'text');
  }

  quantity_input.before('<a href="#decrease_quantity" data-group-id="1" class="quantity_dec_button">-</a>').after('<a href = "#increase_quantity" data-groupid="1" class = "quantity_inc_button" > + </a>');
}

// Handle quantity buttons
// Increment/Decrement button functionality
function increment_decrement_quantity(element, value) {
  $(document.body).on('click', element, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    quantity = $(this).parent().find(('input'));
    quantity_value = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);
    quantity_multiple = undefined;

    if (quantity.data('multiple') !== undefined && (quantity.data('multiple') > 0 || quantity.data('multiple') < 0)) {
      quantity_multiple = parseInt(quantity.data('multiple'), 10);
      if (value < 0) {
        quantity_multiple = quantity_multiple * -1;
      }
    }

    if (quantity_multiple !== undefined && (quantity_multiple > 0 || quantity_multiple < 0)) {
      quantity_value = Math.floor(quantity_value / quantity_multiple) * quantity_multiple;
      value = quantity_multiple;
    } else {
      value = parseInt(value, 10);
    }

    // Validate quantity and increment/decrement value
    if (value > 0 || value < 0 && quantity_value > 0) {
      quantity.val(quantity_value + value).trigger('change');
    }
  });
}

// Remove number type and add quantity change buttons
add_quantity_buttons('.ContentCell input[name^="cartlist_quantity"]', true);

// Decrement button
increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_dec_button', -1);

// Increment button
increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_inc_button', +1);

// Quantity input validation
var ajax_called = false;
$(document.body).on('propertychange change click keyup input paste blur', '.inc_dec_quantity_field', function(e) {
  character_code = !e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode;
  quantity_value = $(this).val();
  leading_zero_plus_regexp = /^(0[0-9]|\+[\+,0-9]).*$/;

  // When input goes out of focus validate quantity value
  if (e.type == 'blur' && (quantity_value == '' || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == true || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value <= 0)) {
    $(this).val('0');
  } else {
    // Check for numeric value and allow backspace, delete, left and right arrows
    if ((isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value > 0) || (character_code != undefined && (character_code == 39 || character_code == 37 || character_code == 8 || character_code == 46))) {
      // Correct value
      // Make sure the quantity is integer
      if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
        $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
      }
    } else if (character_code != undefined) {
      // Incorrect value
      $(this).val('0');
    } else if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
      // Make sure the quantity is integer
      $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
    }
  }

  // AJAX update quantity
  //if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper') && !ajax_called) {
  //if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().hasClass('list_product_qty_wrapper[data-groupid="' + jQuery(this).data("groupid") + '"]') && !ajax_called) {
 // if (e.type != 'click' && $(e.target).parent().parent().data('groupid') == jQuery(this).data("groupid") && !ajax_called) { changed to this after suggestion from Ivan (SO)
  if (e.type != 'click' && $('.quantity_inc_button').data("groupid") == $(e.target).data('groupid') && !ajax_called) { // Ivan (SO) suggestion didn't give an 'OK' in console log. Removing .parent().parent(), it does give an ok, but still only submits the last group to AJAX update 
    console.log('input groupid: ' + $(e.target).data('groupid'));
     console.log('button groupid: ' + $('.quantity_inc_button').data("groupid"));
     console.log('OK')
   // call_delay(function() {
   //   var form = $('form[name="cartlist"]');
   //   ajax_called = true;
   //   $.ajax({
   //     type: form.attr('method'),
   //     url: form.attr('action'),
   //     data: form.serialize()
   //   }).success(function(data) {

   //   if ($('#cartlistDefault').length && $(data).find('#cartlistDefault').length) {
    //    $('#cartlistDefault').replaceWith($(data).find('#cartlistDefault'));

          // Remove number type and add quantity change buttons
    //      add_quantity_buttons('#listContentsDisplay input[name^="cartlist_quantity"]', true);
          // Replace classes missing after AJAX callback
    //      $('select').addClass('select_caret_icon form-control');
    //      if ($('input[type="submit"].cssButton').length > 0) {
    //        $('input[type="submit"].cssButton').attr("data-btn", "btn btn-md");
    //      }
    //    }

    //    ajax_called = false;
   //   }).fail(function(data) {
   //     ajax_called = false;
   //   });
   // }, 300);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ContentCell list_product_qty_wrapper nbr nbt">
  <input type="text" name="cartlist_quantity" data-groupid="1" value="1" size="4" class="cart_input_1881" />
  <input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="1881" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cartlist_group_id" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work, nothing was submitted. No errors in console.

Comment: @Steph3071 paste your current html with the buttons that you are talking about because i dont see it on your post or debugg the code with console.log('OK') in if statement

Comment: No result from console.log('OK') I've updated the question with the entire script which is used to generate the buttons on the qty field, and do the AJAX request